# Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a+\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{2\pi a}{(a^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a+\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{2\pi a}{(a^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
> $$

This is an exercise in Stein's *Complex Analysis*.

By letting $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a+\cos\theta)^2}=4\int_C\frac{dz}{iz(z+\bar z+2a)^2},
$$
where $C$ is the unit circle.

I find that $z+\bar z+2a$ has no zero in the closure of the unit disc. So by the residual formula, I get
$$
\int_C\frac{dz}{iz(z+\bar z+2a)^2}=\frac{2\pi}{4a^{2}},
$$
which is false.
Note that $\bar z$ is not a holomorphic function, so how to use the residual formula?

Comment: Instead of ${\bar z}$ use $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without complex analysis, for any $a>1$ we have
$$ J(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a+\cos\theta}=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a+\cos\theta}=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{a+\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{a-\cos\theta}\right)\,d\theta $$
or
$$ J(a) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2a d\theta}{a^2-\cos^2\theta}\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arctan t}{=}2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2a\,dt}{a^2(1+t^2)-1}\stackrel{t\mapsto s/a}{=}4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{s^2+(a^2-1)}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}. $$
The given integral just equals $-J'(a)=\frac{2\pi a}{(a^2-1)^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R(x)=\frac1{(x+a)^2}$. You want to compute $\int_0^{2\pi}R(x)\,\mathrm dx$. Now, let$$g(z)=\frac1zR\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}2\right)=\frac{4z}{\left(2az+z^2+1\right)^2}.$$Then$$\int_0^{2\pi}R(x)\,\mathrm dx=i\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}g(z)\,\mathrm dz$$and, by the residue theorem, this is integral is the sum of the residues of $g$ in the open unit disk times $2\pi$. Can you take it from here?